# loading liveicons, eve is not defined using requirejs

Tags: javascript, requirejs, raphael

I hope Someone can **explain me**, what's wrong with this code ?

```
require.config({

shim: {
    'eve':{
        exports: 'eve'
    },
    'raphael': {
        deps: ['eve', 'jquery']
    },

     'livicons': {
        deps: ['eve']
    }
},

paths: {

    // Modules
    'eve': 'vendor/eve',
    'jquery': 'vendor/jquery.min',
    'raphael': 'vendor/raphael-min',
    'livicons': 'vendor/livicons-demo-1.2.min'
}

});


require( ['eve','livicons'],function(eve){

   console.log(eve);

});
```

console.log(eve) // You are running Eve 0.4.2

but in the livicons file is not defined when it suppose to be load

Comment: The statement "the livicons file is not defined" does not make much sense. Do you mean to say that the *module* is not defined? That the file is not *loaded*? Something else? Also, you would tremendously increase your chances to get an answer if you provided some context as to what Eve is and how it is supposed to relate to livicons. The set of people who can answer RequireJS questions like yours is relatively small, if those who would answer your question also *have* to already know Eve and livicons, this is reducing the set even further.

Comment: ohh no .. I mean Eve is not defined in livecons file, I had this code in liveicons: a.eve=eve .. but eve is not defined..I'm think eve is a dependency of raphael.Js for work with svg.. it suppose to load If I use 'livicons': {
        deps: ['eve']
    }

Answer (score 1):

Update raphael script to "Raphaël 2.1.2" and above.

```
    'eve': {
        exports: 'eve'
    },
    'raphael': {
        deps: ['eve', 'jquery']
    },
    'livicons': {
        deps: ['eve', 'raphael','jquery']
    }
```